# Why type conversion does not work with += operator?

Tags: c++, oop, type-conversion, double

I wrote the following code as a practice for my OOP exam:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class doble
{
public:
    doble(double D):d(D){}
    inline operator double(){return d;}
private:
    double d;
};

int main()
{
    doble a = 1.5, b = 10.5;
    doble c = 5.25, d = c;
    cout << c / d * b + b * c - c * c / b + b / c << endl; //65

    d = a = b += c;
    cout << d <<" "<< a <<" "<< b <<" "<< c << endl; //15,75 15,75 15,75 5,25
}
```

I get an error in the line with the operator '+=' that says: 'no operator "+=" matches these operands'.
I don't know what else can I do because the overloading of arithmetic operators, assignment, insertion, or the use of friendly functions is not allowed in this exercise.

Thank you!

I thought that with the conversion to double, the operator '+=' will work with doble.

Comment: Both side of the operator have the same type, so no type conversion is done.

Comment: "_because the overloading of arithmetic operators, assignment, insertion, or the use of friendly functions is not allowed in this exercise._": You didn't say what the exercise actually asks you to do, but if your goal is to get your `main` to work as it is, then this restriction makes no sense and makes the task impossible. But maybe the intention is that `+=` overloading as allowed, since that is a _compound assignment operator_, not an _assignment operator_ or an _arithmetic operator_.

Comment: *"I thought that with the conversion to double, the operator '+=' will work with doble."* -- could you explain how you see this working? From my perspective, converting `b` to `double` would create a temporary `double` value, so if that made `+=` work, then `b += c` would modify the temporary `double`, not `b` itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your example works if you defined the operator `+=` properly.

```cpp
    doble& operator += ( const doble& rhs ) {
        d += rhs.d;
        return *this;
    }
```

Produces

```
Program stdout
65
15.75 15.75 15.75 5.25
```

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/rnsMf7aYh

Answer (score 0):

> I thought that with the conversion to double, the operator '+=' will work with doble.

The **problem** is that both of the operands `b` and `c` are of the same type so there is no type conversion to `double` required here. Moreover, since you've not overloaded `operator+=` for `doble`, it produces the mentioned error.

---

> I don't know what else can I do

To **solve** this you can overload `operator+=`:

```
#include <iostream>


class doble
{
public:
    doble(double D):d(D){}
    inline operator double(){return d;}
    //overload operator+=
     doble& operator+=(const doble& rhs) 
    {                           
        /* addition of rhs to *this takes place here */
        d+=rhs.d;
        return *this; // return the result by reference
    }
private:
    double d;
};

int main()
{
    doble b = 10.5;
    doble c = 5.25;
    b += c;
    std::cout << b << c;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4GeGbb9rz)